# Computing homology with cellular complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have a space $M$ of degree $n$ and I want to attach a $n+2$-cell to it using a degree $k$ map.

Let's say $M=S^n$, then I think the cellular complex looks like

$$\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}  $$

I know how to compute the homology if this were a degree $n+1$ cell but how does the degree come into play here?

Comment: What is a space "of degree $n$"?

Comment: If you have a chain complex with no two consecutive nonzero terms, then it's homology is itself!

Comment: @Tyrone Sorry that word shouldn't be there.

Comment: You might like to revise your question with an edit to make it a little clearer.

Comment: @Tyrone I did. It's just an $n+2$-cell.

Comment: The question remains: What is a space of degree $n$?